# Which complete graphs can be embedded on a torus?

Tags: graph-theory

The aim is to embed complete graphs on a torus in such a way that edges don't cross and the faces are homeomorphic to discs.

I found out that the complete graphs K6, K5 and K4 can be embedded on a torus. But what is with K3? I don't think so but how can this be proven properly?

There is a theorem that a graph can only be embedded on a surface when graph and surface have the same Euler characteristic. K3 has 2 and torus has 0. But K4 has also 2 and can nevertheless be embedded on a torus. What am I missing here?

Comment: How do you define the Euler characteristic of a general graph?

Comment: (number of vertices) - (number of edges) + (number of faces)

Comment: How exactly do you know how many faces it has without an a priori embedding?

Comment: I know that K3 and K4 are planar graphs and that planar graphs always have Euler characteristic 2.

Comment: But $K_4$ is also embeddable in the torus, so why isn't the Euler characteristic 0? The point is that graphs don't have Euler characteristics, embeddings do. The embedding on the plane has 4 faces, so $V-E+F=2$. The embedding on the torus has 2 (non-cellular) faces, so $V-E+F=0$. Euler's formula holds in both cases, the fallacy is applying it to the graph instead of the embedding. You can define the maximum and minimum genus of a graph, but you can't define a unique genus.

Comment: But in our lecture the graph itself has an Euler characteristic. So this is wrong? How would you prove then that K3 can't be embedded on a torus?

Comment: You've shown that $K_4$ has embedding onto two different surfaces with different genuses, so the notion of the genus of a graph it ambiguous. I suggest you ask your lecturer for clarification. Proving something is not embeddable is in general rather difficult. For $K_3$ on the torus however, we can do so by contradiction. Suppose $K_3$ had a $2$-cell embedding (all faces homeomorphic to a disk) onto the torus. Then Euler's formula applies and we must have $V-E+F = \chi = 0$. Since $V=E=3$, this implies we have $F=0$, which is clearly impossible.

Comment: Fascinating! I have learned from you that a graph doesn't necessarily have the same F in all embeddings but F is nonetheless useful for contradictory purposes. Thank you!

Comment: @EuYu You should summarize all this as an answer.